# Installing Windows 10 IoT Core on an x86/x64 Device

Tags: windows, 64-bit, iot

I am struggling to find good documentation or guides and how to's on Installing Windows 10 IoT Core on an x86/x64 Device.
I found this guide https://www.concurrency.com/blog/july-2018/beginning-iot-%E2%80%93-installing-windows-10-iot-core-on

However it seems alot has changed since that guide was written for pictures 2,3,4 on my screen are different.

My question is does anyone have a good guide/how to's for Installing Windows 10 IoT Core on an x86/x64 Device?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't specify how those screenshots are different.  I see nothing that would be inaccurate about that guide.  Be sure you download the correct ADK for whichever version of Windows IoT you are building.  [IoT ADK](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/) fully supports 1809.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I guess I perceiving I am doing something wrong and I am having trouble inferring what i am doing wrong. typical i would sus this out by looking at other guides.

Comment: But to specify, i do not see the SetOEM.CMD file and nor do i see the installoemcerts.cmd file. when i run the IoTCoreShell.cmd  it doesn't ask me to set the architecture and looks abit different.

Comment: Have you installed the [pre-requisites](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/blob/master/Tools/README.md)?  While you are correct the guide is slightly outdated, in that you don't need [this](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit) provided you are building an 1809 image.  If you are building a different IoT image, edit your question, and provide the required information to answer your question.